# Youtube channels like one of Paul Davis or Adam Neely but with focus on violin

Tags: violin

Im in the look for youtube channels to subscribe myself to of professional violinists talking and playing about both the theorycal and practical sides of the violinist life. 
I love the way this young guys express and explain so well with so many examples and images.

Comment: Questions which are requests for external resources are [off-topic here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm a violinist -- never held a bass in my life -- but I still watch and get stuff out of Adam Neely's channel. A violin specific channel would only offer slightly more specific information, when a lot can already be cross-applied from the channels you've already mentioned.